# Why are images uploaded through the admin panel of my custom module, having the file name of Array?

Tags: magento

Here is my BrandController.php
https://gist.github.com/a958926883b9e7cc68f7#file-brandcontroller-php-L53

I've gone through all my files of my custom module, and compared them to the one given from the custom module maker, and I couldn't find much differences.

Comment: how are you displaying it in your template (i.e. the code)? when you var_dump it what does it show you?

Comment: I'm just showing the value that's in the database which is `Array`

Answer (score 2):

Are you attempting to upload multiple files? If you're using multiple fileupload elements with the same name you'll get an array of items.

So when the following line is called,

```
//this way the name is saved in DB
$data['filename'] = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
```

It will have the value

```
["name"]=>array(2) {
      [0]=>string(9)"file0.txt"
      [1]=>string(9)"file1.txt"
}
```

you'll need to update the code to loop through each $_FILES['filename']['name'] and upload and save the files separately.

Comment: But I'm only uploading 1 image and not 2. https://gist.github.com/desbest/ba742160cdd37a970c7e

Answer (score 2):

You may unknowingly uploaded multiple files. If you that is not your intention, you may check your  in your HTML and check the name attribute of the  tag. It must **not** be an array (like this).

```
<input type="file" name="my_files[]" />
```

If you only see Array() in your database, it means you are indeed uploading a multiple files. You can process them by using loops.

If you are really sure that you are uploading 1 image, you may follow @Palanikumar's suggestion. Use a print_r() and display the $_FILES and paste it here. IF you don't want to use that, You can use

```
json_encode($the-data-you-are-going-to-insert-to-the-database);
```

If you don't know where to put the print_r() function, you may put it after line 56 of this file.

https://gist.github.com/desbest/a958926883b9e7cc68f7#file-brandcontroller-php-L53

```
if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && $_FILES['filename']['name'] != '') {
 print_r($_FILES);
 die;
```

If saveAction() is being called inside an ajax function you need to log the ajax response. Assuming you are using jquery..

```
$ajaxResponse = $.POST({...});
console.log($ajaxResponse.responseText);
```

Then, you you can view it inside a browser's console. If nothing appears, you may use a non-async request

```
$ajaxResponse = $.POST({
    // your options,
    // your another option,
    async: FALSE
});
```

Comment: Putting the `print_r` after line 56 doesn't do anything.

Comment: how about putting it before?

Comment: I put it before, and it worked. Thanks. I've figured out half of it. I had to change `filename` to `imagepath`, to match the name of the form field. Now the image uploads in the folder it should, which is an improvement. My new problem is that Line 84 is NOT saving the file name as it should, and is just saying `Array`. https://gist.github.com/desbest/f904aff0d090e14a1663#file-brandcontroller-php-L83

Answer (score 1):

Usually file upload will return in array format. So that each uploaded file will have the information like name, type, size, temporary name, error. You can get the file information using print function (**print_r($_FILES)**). So if you want to display name of the file you have to use something like this **$_FILES['filename']['name']**

Use print function and debugging tool then save file information using loops.

For more info please check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the enctype of the form so the image will never be sent. updated the code to

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array( 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
```